# Trying to calculate a new field in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

Im new to SQL server and SQL in general, I have calculated a field for 'total price' from ((unitprice*discount)*Quantity) by a query within MS access and am trying to do the same in SQL Server as seen below:

```
SELECT OrderDetails.ProductID, 
       OrderDetails.Quantity,
       OrderDetails.Discount, 
       OrderDetails.UnitPrice AS **[Original Price]**, 
       [Original Price]-(UnitPrice*Discount)*Quantity AS [Total Cost]
FROM OrderDetails;
```

I have highlights the original price which is flagging for me in SQL server in bold.

Can anybody please help me out?

Comment: `select foo as bar, bar*baz` is illegal sql. in some cases you can do `select foo as bar ... where bar=...` and the like, but within the field list, you cannot use aliases defined in an earlier field

Comment: I'm not sure you got the brackets correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Just to spell out what @MarcB was saying, you have to just repeat the column names in your `SELECT` statement:

```
SELECT od.roductID, 
       od.Quantity,
       od.Discount, 
       od.UnitPrice AS OriginalPrice
       od.UnitPrice - (od.UnitPrice*od.Discount)*od.Quantity AS Total_Cost
FROM OrderDetails od
```

It is not so verbose if you give the `OrderDetails` table an alias (`od` in this case).

Comment: If the formula is complex. you could also use cross apply to calculate new columns and that way refer to the previous ones

Comment: @JamesZ Why not post that as another answer?

Comment: It sounded like this a simple case that doesn't really need that... and I was feeling lazy ;)

Comment: Also avoid using spaces in your names of tables/fields/aliases. You are making your code much less readable and much more bug prone.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use alias name in calculation of other column. You can write in following way:

```
SELECT ProductID, Quantity,Discount, UnitPrice AS [Original Price], 
       UnitPrice-(UnitPrice*Discount)*Quantity AS [Total Cost]
FROM OrderDetails
```